# DSLR macro vs iPhone 5s with Olloclip macro lens

Tags: macro, iphone, comparison

[image]
[image]
[image]

I captured these photos using an iPhone 5s, Camera + with Olloclip macro lens. I wonder, would it give more sharpness/details if these were taken using a DSLR with a macro lens?

Assume printing at approximately A5-size, 148 x 210mm (5.8 x 8.3 in).

Comment: You're going to have to define "better" for this question to not simply be a guessing game.

Comment: Hi @nish1013. I've taken the liberty to remove the request for photo critique from your question ([which are off-topic here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/should-photo-critiques-be-allowed)). I did this to hopefully avoid quick negative reaction to your question (and probably downvotes). If you feel I have substantially altered your question or your intent, you can revert my edit if you wish.

Comment: @scottbb thank you so much. So what are the suitable places/site to request photo critiques?

Comment: I don't know, but I would start with a Google search. Here at Photo.SE, I'd start with [What's the best way to get constructive critique of your photographs?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/4698). Googling "photo critique" immediately produced these: [r/photocritique](https://www.reddit.com/r/photocritique/) at Reddit; [Flickr photo critique group](https://www.flickr.com/groups/photographycritique/); [1x](https://1x.com/critique). Also, you could ask in chat here at Photo.SE. People are usually willing to chime in and help there.

Comment: Please note that a [later community consensus](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/can-we-re-open-the-door-to-something-a-little-like-photo-critique) brought a limited form of photo critique back on-topic here.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Yes, but I suspect that as originally written, the question wouldn't have passed muster of that meta question guidelines. While the issue is nuanced, it is still listed as (mostly) OT in the help center.

Comment: The more glass you have in front of the sensor the less sharp an image is going to be as the light had to get through and bounce around various lenses. So of course a DSLR with a proper macro lens is going to produce sharper images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone attachments *can* produce reasonably good results. But, quality of those attachments ranges far and wide. Some are super cheap, going so far as to use plastic lens elements instead of glass.

Assuming your attachment is of good quality, then the usual iPhone/DSLR differences apply. The iPhone, having such a small sensor, needs an incredibly well lit environment to take a low noise photo. This may simply not be possible.

Additionally, macro attachments require you to be very very close to your subject. If your subject is alive, you're probably not getting the shot as you'll scare it off.

The DSLR will have different macro focal lengths, allowing you to pick how far you want to be to produce a 1:1 shot. You'll also benefit from the use of a good tripod and macro focusing rails, if needed. Additionally, flash can be used to greater effect.

To sum it up, in a well lit environment with stationary objects, an iPhone and DSLR may be able to compete head to head in terms of image quality. Outside of this, the DSLR still gives you the ability to get the shot, while the iPhone will leave you looking at the photos others have taken (with their SLR).